# Active configuration

Tags: visual-studio

Where exactly in a Visual Studio project is the active configuration (*release*, *debug*, etc.) stored?

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly sure that's stored in the .suo file. It's a binary file that stores various user/machine specific settings and you can find more information about this file [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909.aspx).

Comment: it's indeed in the .suo file; debug settings etc are stred per-project in the vcproj.user file though

Comment: Thanks , indeed I found  it  in csproj.user