# Active configuration for solutions SharpDevelop

Tags: sharpdevelop

I [already asked regarding the active configuration for Visual Studio projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184264/active-configuration) and thanks to that already, I know that it is stored in .suo and csproj.user (for C#) file.

Now I found that for solutions created in [SharpDevelop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharpDevelop) there were not created these files.

Where is information for the active configuration for solutions created in SharpDevelop stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharpDevelop this information is stored in an XML file under your user profile. In [Windows Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista) and [Windows 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7), for example, this XML file is stored in the folder:

```
C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\ICSharpCode\SharpDevelop3.0\preferences
```

Inside this folder will be an XML file named after your solution (e.g., *MyConsoleApp.sln.3f6fc903.xml*). The XML file will store the currently active configuration as shown below:

```
<Properties>
  <ActiveConfiguration value="Debug" />
  <ActivePlatform value="x86" />
  <StartupProject value="" />
</Properties>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick and very helpful reply .
In addition : for Win XP it located in 
C:\Documents and Settings\\[username]\Application Data\ICSharpCode\SharpDevelop3.0\preferences\\[solutionname].xml